# Converting DateTime to String in SQL Server & Postgres

Tags: sql-server, postgresql

I've datetime value `2020-06-29 18:12:23` and I am trying to convert this to `20200629181223`format in both SQL Server & Postgres

Any thoughts please? Thanks!

Comment: What have you tried? Both have a bunch of datetime + string functions.

Comment: You may take adavantage from [Postfres Data Type Formatting Functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-formatting.html) with `to_char(current_timestamp, 'HH12:MI:SS')`. Similar is available in SQL Server documentation.

Comment: You won't find a single SQL that works for both systems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is easy with a convert and nested replace functions:

```
select replace(replace(replace(convert(varchar,getdate(),120),' ',''),'-',''),':','')
```

Comment: Thanks Tom. Was trying with CONVERT(), but didn't think of using REPLACE function.

Answer (score 3):

You can also use `to_char` method like following on postgres

`to_char(created_date, 'dd/mm/yyyy')`

created_date is of type `timezone with timezone` here

You can read more use cases [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-formatting.html)

Answer (score 2):

In Postgres using to_char():

```
select to_char('2020-06-29 18:12:23'::timestamp, 'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS');
    to_char     
----------------
 20200629181223
```